# Change URL Path when refreshing site with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm searching for a lightweight way to change the URL by refreshing the site. Or detect when the URL is an error 404 and redirect it immediately back to the homepage.

I saw some ways with jQuery but I really just want to use something lightweight.

more info:
I'm building a onepager Portfolio which changes sites immediately without refreshing. but I want the to behave like a normal page, So I found a way to change the URL Path so when I click a link it also shows on which page I am in the URL.

The problem is when I refresh the page it wants to load the fake URL which is obviously not existing. So I need a way to change the URL when I refresh to a wrong URL Path.

I will be super thankful if someone has a solution for me because a dream would become true.

Comment: What you want is a bit like you'd want to solder a wire with a volcano, a wrong tool for the purpose ...

Comment: does it sound that crazy? I mean there is a way to make custome error 404 pages and maybe i can redirect from the error page or something like that?

Comment: The purpose (and the native built-in behavior) of the refresh button in a browser is to reload the current page. If you're overriding that behavior, your visitors get confused. If you need custom error pages, please consult the manual of your server, error pages are created on the server, and are customizable.

Answer (score 0):

when you refresh, browser sends the URI to server to parse it, so there is no way to redirect it client side(ie. javascript)

you have to set up redirect on the server.

what backend are you using? are you using nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Otherwise if you want to set it up a simple page all yourself I would just use CSS `visibility` in your logic while changing the URL.